# How to make layout white with animation? Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to make my layout white with animation. It got a drawable background. I want to make with some duration smooth animation which makes the background white.
Is it possible? How to make it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Fade-in-Fade-out

The animation that you are asking is `Fade-in-Fade-out`, which fade out the Drawable background and fade in the white background.

You need to create XML animation. This answer is too broad suggested to see the [AndroidHive tutorial about this.](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/)

[image]